# Spring batch read from xml file and write to Database. need step1 auto generated key for step2

Tags: mysql, xml, spring, spring-batch

As seen in below code in step1 I'm reading users.xml and writing to database now  in step2 I'm reading from userdetails.xml and writing to database but I need step1 auto generated key of tbl_user for step2. How Can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"        
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="../config/context.xml" />
<import resource="../config/database.xml" />               


<bean id="xmlItemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/users.xml" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="user" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="userUnmarshaller"/>                    
</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemReader2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/userdetails.xml" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="userdetail" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="userUnmarshaller"/>                    
</bean>

<bean id="itemProcessor1" class="com.qmetry.recovery.mapper.UserItemProcessor" />

<bean id="itemProcessor2" class="com.qmetry.recovery.mapper.UserDetailItemProcessor" />

<job id="testJob2" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step2_1">
            <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <chunk reader="xmlItemReader1" writer="databaseItemWriter1" processor="itemProcessor1"
                       commit-interval="100" />
            </tasklet>                
        <listeners>                
            <listener ref="testListener" />
        </listeners>            
        </step>
        <step id="step2_2">
            <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <chunk reader="xmlItemReader2" writer="databaseItemWriter2" processor="itemProcessor1"
                       commit-interval="100" />
            </tasklet>                
        </step>            
</job>
<bean id="testListener" class="com.qmetry.recovery.mapper.TestListener" scope="step" />

<bean id="databaseItemWriter1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into TBL_USER(USERNAME,EMAILID) 
                values (?, ?)                        
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

     <!--We need a custom setter to handle the conversion between Jodatime LocalDate and MySQL DATE BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider--> 
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.qmetry.recovery.mapper.UserItemPreparedStatementSetter"/>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="databaseItemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into TBL_USERDETAIL(USERID,CONTACT) 
                values (?, ?)
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

     <!--We need a custom setter to handle the conversion between Jodatime LocalDate and MySQL DATE BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider--> 
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.qmetry.recovery.mapper.UserDetailItemPreparedStatementSetter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><users>
    <user>
        <userId>1</userId>
        <userName>Taher</userName>
        <emailId>taher.tinwala@hotmail.com</emailId>
    </user>
</users>
```

userdetails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><userdetails>
    <userdetail>
        <userDetailId>1</userDetailId>
        <userId__TblUser>1</userId__TblUser>
        <contact>1111111111</contact>
    </userdetail>
    <userdetail>
        <userDetailId>2</userDetailId>
        <userId__TblUser>1</userId__TblUser>
        <contact>2222222222</contact>
    </userdetail>
    <userdetail>
        <userDetailId>4</userDetailId>
        <userId__TblUser>1</userId__TblUser>
        <contact>4444444444</contact>
    </userdetail>
</userdetails>
```

Comment: There must be something else in the `userdetails.xml` that correlates to the user. How do you determine that it belongs to a user from one xml file to another?

Comment: XMLs which I am having i had generated using spring batch read from db tables and write to xml. Now I have to implement it vice versa i.e. read from that xml and write to database.

Comment: Let me rephrase the comment. How are you going to know which part of the user details belongs to the same user? Also why even export 2 xml files why not simply 1? What you want is, without additional information in one of the xml files, not possible. Either put everything in a single xml, or read both xml files together (you can then correlate the user-id from one to another file).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data to a future step. For explantory documentation see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

I have implemented the example from the documentation and adjusted it to your configuration with some assumptions here and there.

During the read (or the write, it depends when you get the data that you want to pass) in step 1 you need to store the data in the StepExecution. Add to your xmlItemReader the following:

```
public class YourItemReader implements ItemReader<Object>
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    public void read(Object item) throws Exception {
        // ...

        ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("tbl_user", someObject);
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
```

Your xml will look like this:

```
<step id="step2_1">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="xmlItemReader1" writer="databaseItemWriter1" processor="itemProcessor1" commit-interval="100" />
    </tasklet>                
    <listeners>                
        <listener ref="testListener" />
        <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
    </listeners>
</step>
```

Add the promotionListener bean:

```
<beans:bean id="promotionListener" class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <beans:property name="keys" value="tbl_key"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And finally you need to retrieve the value in step 2. Again asuming you need it in the reader of step 2 you reader in step 2 needs the following code added:

```
public class YourItemReader2 implements ItemReader<Object>
    private Object someObject;

    @BeforeStep
    public void retrieveInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        this.someObject = jobContext.get("tbl_key");
    }
```

Now you have acces to the value read in step 1.

**EDIT - adding some example configuration for an extra read step:**

After step 1 add a simple step 2 with the following reader to get the new value from the database

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />            
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                YOUR SELECT STATEMENT
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapper" />     
</bean>
```

And a simple rowMapper bean

```
<bean id="rowMapper" class="exampleRowMapper" />
```

You will have to write your exampleRowMapper obviously to reflect the data your fetching. For example:

```
public class ExampleRowMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<String> {

    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return String.valueOf(rs.getString(1));
    }

}
```

In your dummywriter you add the stepexecution and you will store your value in the step execution context.:

```
public class DummyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Object> item) throws Exception {
        ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("someKey", someObject);
    }    
}
```

And the bean for the writer:

```
<bean id="savingDummyWriter" class="your.package.DummyItemWriter" />
```

And wrap the reader and writer in a step.

```
<step id="step2">
    <tasklet>    
        <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="dummyItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />    
    </tasklet>        
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="promotionListener"/>
    </listeners>
</step>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My case is little bit different. In step1 I'm reading from xml and writing to tbl_user table now that row is generating new Primary key when inserted in DB I want that key in step2 as foriegn key for tbl_userdetail

Comment: Please add that information to your question and adjust your question to better reflect the actual problem. So if I understand correct after step 1 you created a row in your db. Just fetch the full row in an added intermediate step, get the information you need and use the promotionlistener to pass that information to step 3.

Comment: Let me explain you as in users.xml userId=1 in both users.xml and userdetails.xml but when I write again to DB userId it get as auto generated as 10, userId=10 now so in userdetails.xml I need to udpate userId=10 instead of 1. For that itemwriter1 should give newly generated userId

Comment: Fetch the newly generated userId with an intermediate step (reader-dummywriter or even a tasklet) and pass it to the next step as explained in my answer.

Comment: Can you update the answer as I am not getting how to do that

Comment: Added some example code. Try making it work like that. Good luck!